# How do I play a sound without any interference with the UI of my program?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, audio, user-interface

my app aims to play some sound rhythmically following some mathematical formulas. In other version of this program developed for other platform I just "sleep" the thread the time needed until I need to play the next sound but in android, if you sleep the process the UI sleeps as well. I try the next code as an example, trying to separate the UI and the sound process:

```
public class SoundThread extends Thread{
private MediaPlayer player;
SoundThread(Context context)
{
    player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.ex);
}
public void run()
{
    for(int x=0;x<100;x++)
    {
        player.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This class starts mediaplayer with an example sound and the context of the activity that is calling it and it is supposed to play R.raw.ex every second. But when I call it from my activity I hear that the sound plays correctly but my device consider that the app is frozen.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular application, if you don't need playback control, you can just wrap that bit of code up in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

If you want to be able to control playback, then you should [implement a Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices).

Comment: That's probably not going to work as `AsyncTask` will be put on a queue delaying the audio by enough to be noticeable (so failing the requirement for playing sound rhythmically).

Comment: Yes, I have been reading about this class and the main problem is that the sound requirements are a bit exigents. But thank you very much.